# Преобразовать строку в логическое выражение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

например есть выражение str(0 != 0) нужно проверить верное ли это выражение
Без создания дополнительного движка.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "проверить"? `str(0 != 0)` будет равно строке `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval('0 != 0')`
Но вы должны понимать, что это небезопасно, так как в строке может быть вредоносный код